# Can azure DPS enrolment process integrated with SAP or any other CRM?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

**background:** on each order from a customer a invoice is created for device manufacturing with an unique serial number which identifies the device.

is it possible to add add newly created device(invoice) automatically to enrolment list of Device Provisioning list via SAP or CRM through some api calls? soon after a invoice is created?

how can device replacement be handled in IoT scenario?